# How do I make the ajax run?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, onchange, keyup

When I add the ajax it only runs once.

I try that when I enter a letter in the search engine or change a select field, it sends me the new search to display it on the screen.

formMenu is a form containing a select and an imput text.

```
 $('#formMenu').on('keyup change',function() {    
                 
         $.ajax(
                      {
                        url: '/calendar',
                        success: function( data ) {
                          $('body').html(data);
                        }
                      }
                    );
      });
```

Comment: What is  "#formMenu" ?  A button  ,  Textbox , Selectbox??  share the HTML element.. 

If possible check the console if you can see the error

Comment: formMenu is a form containing a select and an imput text

Comment: Just want to confirm again.  Is that (same) ID given to an input box and select box both ?

Comment: no, they are different

Comment: Tried with my answer and did that work ? Meanwhile if you can please share your both the HTML elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Try using the below.

```
$(document).on('keyup change', '#formMenu', function() {
  // Your Ajax Call here
})
```

Comment: thank you very much, it is working. can you explain me why the id is put after the Change and Keyup methods?

Comment: @Kimi29 , https://elijahmanor.com/blog/differences-between-jquery-bind-vs-live-vs-delegate-vs-on  This article will more helpfull to you

Answer (score -1):

You instance of `#formMenu` is not existing after you replace the body even if the same element exists in the new body its still a different instance.
You have to register the listener on the highest parent that is not replaced (in this case the body):

```
$("body").on("keyup change", "#formMenu", function() {
  //ajax call
});
```